# Android Google Maps V2 Title or Snippets Strings From HTML

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i'm working on a google maps v2 project on Android and i need to write a bit HTML code (like a page) and implement it to google marker's title or snippet.

I know there are ways like : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/ here but i need to write **HTML codes** because after this work **i will use these codes again in another mobile project.**

***Any help would be appreciated, thanks***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker), you are able to customize the content and design of info windows.
If this is so, then you could define a custom layout with few `TextViews`, which then is very easy to set html text in it:

```
Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(htmlString);
textView.setText(spannedContent, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Also, you may want to take a look and [browse these example projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2) on how to use Map V2 in various ways.